# Quarto Render having diff of engine output timed out issue

Tags: jupyter, render, quarto

My quarto convert and quarto check commands work just fine. However, whenever I try quarto render, the process seems to work up until the very last .qmd file. That .qmd file seems to work, except after the last cell is processed, the python3 kernel doesn't start and I get a diff of engine timed-out error. I have added a picture of this error and would greatly appreciate any help! For reference, I'm using jupyterlab to edit files and build my notebook locally.

[image: my bug].

For reference, here is quarto check:

```
[✓] Checking Quarto installation......OK
      Version: 1.2.313
      Path: /Applications/quarto/bin

[✓] Checking basic markdown render....OK

[✓] Checking Python 3 installation....OK
      Version: 3.11.1
      Path: /Users/rohanjha/.pyenv/versions/3.11.1/bin/python3
      Jupyter: 5.1.5
      Kernels: python388jvsc74a57bd09a5ef3ad2cf8b3fa93c4a614d9bfeb4b16952c775578d4eef30ec91fa30191fe, python3109jvsc74a57bd0f5460abb8cde1d7e4f0714494cefaae4efa91c7291e5f53e0def68448f0569ef, python3

[✓] Checking Jupyter engine render....OK

[✓] Checking R installation...........OK
      Version: 4.2.2
      Path: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources
      LibPaths:
        - /Users/rohanjha/Library/R/arm64/4.2/library
        - /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2-arm64/Resources/library
      rmarkdown: 2.20

[✓] Checking Knitr engine render......OK
```

I tried doing `quarto render`, expecting the entire notebook to be processed.

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out! I was asking quarto to render massive dataframes. The issue went away after I put `.head()` after each data frame

Comment: shafee, I'm experiencing the same problem, or at least the same error message.  What did you mean by "put .head() after each data frame"